# Terminal has changed its default folder to start at

Tags: home, sabayon, cwd

By default, every Linux distributions' Terminal I have used so far starts at `/home/[username]`. For some reason, without noticing, the default folder is now at root in Sabayon.

How do I change the default starting folder in Terminal to be my username folder again?

Comment: I don't use any of those, so this is a complete guess -- but did you happen to start your desktop environment from the root directory? Perhaps they all inherited a cwd of / instead of your typical $HOME

Comment: are you running the terminal as root ? if so, /root is the home directory for root.

Comment: No, I haven't. It suddenly changed by itself.

Comment: Can you post output of `echo $PS1` and `echo $PS2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your initial location to your home by adding

```
cd ~/
```

To your ~/.bashrc

You may also need to check that $HOME is set to your actual home directory

```
export HOME=/home/user_name/
```

Comment: The `.bashrc` file solved it. I don't know why it changed. I hate when these things happen. Maybe it was an update of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Your system probably uses **SElinux**. And after some system upgrade SElinux has changed some internals or gained new properties. Try

```
restorecon -r /home
```

then logout and login again.